# How to search data from two tables in sqlite android?

Tags: android, database, search, android-sqlite

I have two tables in that I want to search particular name,blood group and profession. I have tried a lot but didn't get anything. I'm Using below code for search. Any one can help me please.
Thanks.

"SELECT blood_group from members,keymembers where 'blood_group'"

Comment: i think you should read about JOINS

Comment: I want to know how to search one character in AutocompleteTextView

Answer (score 0):

try this Query

```
SELECT Item.No,Route_Line.No
From Item,Route_Line
Where Route_Line.Item_No = Item.No    //Item & Route_Line are table
                                      //No & Item_No are column name.
```

Use JOIN for what you need. Hope this help.

Comment: What is .No here indicates?

Comment: No is a column Name in Route_Line Table as well as in Item Table.

Comment: I want to know how to search one character in AutocompleteTextView

Comment: set this property of AutoCompleteTextView `autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);` to Search Character.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48126/discussion-between-harish-koona-and-i-n-e-f)

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<Coupon> getMyCoupons(String categoryId,String cardId,boolean isFavorite){
    ArrayList<Coupon> coupons = new ArrayList<Coupon>();
    StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer();
    query.append("SELECT * from " + DatabaseHelper.MY_COUPON_TABLE_NAME); 
    if(categoryId != null && categoryId.length() >0){
        query.append(", MyCouponCatMapping WHERE ");
        query.append(" MyCouponCatMapping.CategoryId = " + categoryId + " AND MyCoupons.Id = MyCouponCatMapping.CouponId");
        if (isFavorite) {
            query.append(" AND MyCoupons.IsFavorite = 1");
        }
    } else if (cardId != null && cardId.length() > 0)   {
        if(categoryId != null && categoryId.length() >0){
            query.append(" AND ");
            query.append("tagCardId = '" + cardId +"'");
        } else  {
            query.append(" WHERE ");
            query.append("tagCardId = '" + cardId +"'");
            if (isFavorite) {
                query.append(" AND MyCoupons.IsFavorite = 1");
            }
        }

    } else if (isFavorite)  {
        query.append(" WHERE MyCoupons.IsFavorite = 1");
    }
    coupons = getCouponArrayFromQuery(query.toString());
    return coupons;
}
```

here u can find ur solution ....if u need simple 1-2 value from database then . do not use arraylist .. use simple method ..